# Mark and Filter duplicates ListObject VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, conditional-statements, listobject

I am trying to find, mark and filter duplicates at ListObject (column of Dynamic Table) VBA without success.
The Following script works great for the regular range, I made some changes and need it for the list object.
I will very much appreciate your assistance

S

```vba
sub Duplicates()
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape3").Select 'change to whatever your shape is called
    If Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse Then
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 40
    Else
    
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    
    End If
    
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    
    'Test for duplicates in a single column
    'Duplicates will be highlighted in red
    
    Set Rng = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    For Each cel In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
    
    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    Next cel
    
    Range("B:J").Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$J$1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
    , 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$J$1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>0", _
    Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use conditional formatting:

```
Sub FilterDups()
Dim LO As ListObject, FC As UniqueValues

Set LO = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1) ' Dynamic Table
Set FC = LO.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues   ' UniqueValues object to quickly visualize cells that contain either unique or duplicate values
With FC
    .SetFirstPriority
    .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    .Interior.Color = vbRed ' red color for duplicate values
End With

LO.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 255), Operator:=xlFilterNoFill ' filter out duplicate values
```

End Sub

[image: Before]
[image: After]
[image: After (ResetFilter)]